# Post Request reassembled TCP segment greater than content-length

Tags: tcp, wireshark, content-length

I used wireshark to check post request and I found that the reassembled TCP segment size greater than the content-length , is that because content-length is for the size of body only ? and the ressambled includes the header ?

```
[3 Reassembled TCP Segments (1664 bytes): #1233(578), #1235(1028), #1237(58)]
[Frame: 1233, payload: 0-577 (578 bytes)]
[Frame: 1235, payload: 578-1605 (1028 bytes)]
[Frame: 1237, payload: 1606-1663 (58 bytes)]
[Segment count: 3]

 [Reassembled TCP length: 1664]
```

---

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
content-length: 1249\r\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that because content-length is for the size of body only

Correct. Content-length describes only the length of the message body. From [the HTTP standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13):

> 14.13 Content-Length
>   The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the **size of the entity-body**, in decimal number of OCTETs ...

> ... and the ressambled includes the header ?

Given that you show parts of the header which is included in the reassembled data these data obviously contain at least part of the header.

Comment: [Reassembled TCP length: 1664] is not only the content length right ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi: again: the content-length header gives the length of the message body only. The reassembled TCP length is likely header and body.